# we can manipulate static arrays of JavaScript. e.g. we can add delete then what this classification is? dynamic and static arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory, dynamic, static

we can add delete elements in every javascript array.
then how we can differentiate whether it is a static array or a dynamic array in Javascript?

Comment: Depends what your definition of static and dynamic are.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: can you please answer it with respect to the standard definition of these?